# Jinja return_query()

Tags: sql, jinja2

I have an SQL query that returns null value within a normal SQL query. eg.

```
my_query = select x from table where col = y
```

When I have this query evaluated in jinja as

```
{% set query_results = run_query(my_query) %}
```

What does this return_query return where there is no values? I hvae read the docs which states it returns none but it doesn't register for me in my subsequent conditional filter below.
When a value is returned (single scalar decimal, I can access via query_results[0][0]. But I am having issues when there is nothing to return.

```
{% if query_results = none %}
 do this
{% else %}
  'do that'
{% endif %}
```

It executes 'do that'.  I have also tried: is defined, = [], ='', etc but can't seem to get the true returned value from the return_query() function.

Am I missing something?

Many Thanks.